# Ruby - Nokogiri returning empty string

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm attempting to pull values from an xml file using nokogiri, but there are no values being returned. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the xml file called "smtp.xml"

```
<options>
    <address>server</address>
    <port>587</port>
    <domain>domain name</domain>
    <user_name>my_user</user_name>
    <password>my_password</password>
</options>
```

Here's my Ruby code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("smtp.xml"))

address = doc.xpath('//options/address').text
puts address
```

'address' is just returning an empty string...

Comment: I ran your code at my end and it does return "server" string

Comment: On my end I just get an empty string. Could it be something environmental on my end? I have the XML file located in the same directory as my ruby file. Do I need to do anything special to grant permissions to view the XML file?

Comment: I can confirm the same results as @ankitg, the 'server' string gets printed.

Comment: I get 'server' too. File also located in the same directory

Comment: I figured it out, it was something weird with my xml file, I don't think it formatting properly in Sublime. I copied the xml over to a plain text file and bam, instant success. Thanks guys

Comment: I see there are also some tutorials and resources on http://www.nokogiri.org/